# Lotka Volterra variation with per capita approach

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

I am reading the article in [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002251938480082X). There are few things that I don't understand in it and can someone please help me to clarify these.

First the Lotka Volterra type predator prey is defined as below with $x_1$ being prey and $x_2$ being predators.

[image]

Then two functional forms are introduces as
  $\phi(x_1)=x_1/(k+x_1)     ----------(1)$  and
$\phi (x_1/x_2)=x_1/(kx_2+x_1)-----------(2)$

Then it is said as resource becomes scarce (the value of $x_1$ no longer dominates $k$) equation (2) reflects the intraspecific competition for resources. I don't understand why only equation (2) reflects this and why equation (1) doesn't? How is this decided?

Then it is said that if $b_i x_1x_2$ is replaced in the Lotka Volterra equation with $b_ix_1\phi(x_2)$ then intraspecific competition for prey is only indirectly accounted for through the increased rate at which the prey are depleted. I don't understand what is meant by this. How does it result in an `increased rate at which the prey are depleted`?
What is it meant by `indirectly accounted`? Doesn't this impact when  $b_i x_1x_2$ is replaced with $b_ix_1\phi(x_2/x_1)$